# Count characters within block of text and split into two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, character

I am trying to convert a block of text into columns automatically as the client doesn't no html / CSS very well.

I wrote this little script to search through a div to find a hr tag and automatically add a class to the p tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if($('#data').find('hr')){
            $('hr').prev('p').addClass('left');
            $('hr').next('p').addClass('right');
        }
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>



<div id="data">

<p>This is paragraph 1. Lorem ipsum ... <br /><br />
This is paragraph 2. Lorem ipsum ... <br /><br />
This is paragraph 3. Lorem ipsum ... </p>
<hr />

<p>This is paragraph 4. Lorem ipsum ... <br /><br />
This is paragraph 5. Lorem ipsum ... <br /><br />
This is paragraph 6. Lorem ipsum ... </p>

</div>
```

But this doesnt work very well if the paragraphs are different lenghts as the right column could be bigger than the left.

so i need to rewrite it to count the characters and split it equally (or as close as with the bigger section on the left.) but i have no idea how to start this. so if you could help that would be fantastic.

Comment: Do you want the width and height to be equal of the two columns, essentially?

Comment: preferably yes although if they are going to be different, id like the left hand column to be the biggest.

Comment: [Does this provide you with a solution?](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/xqgSH/)

Comment: not really,

i want to count the characters within div#data and split it in half as the p.right is alot bigger because there are more characters,

Comment: you don't want to split or every char as this will just cause words to be broken up across the columns

Comment: @Jordan Sayner [How about this is this something more to your akin?](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/xqgSH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First thing this should not be done though JavaScript/jQuery on the render to client you should not build a layout though JavaScript/jQuery only improve it,

But as for your code you can do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/barkermn01/VTQeC/10/

You can then change the splitChar to be a `"."` if you want it to break on sentances or leave it on `" "` if your happy for a word break down

Comment: Hmm. I think sencha might disagree http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/. It depends what you're building and what it'll be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have paragraph tags in the body this should work without too much modification. It should work no matter how many paragraphs you have, and regardless of how the text content is spread between them.

```
/**
 * Create left and right divs
 */
var $left = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass('left');
var $right = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass('right');

/**
 * Store the text lengths into an array
 */
var textLengthArray = [];
var totalLength = 0;
$('p').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    textLengthArray[textLengthArray.length] = text.length;
    totalLength += text.length;
});

/**
 * The midpoint is crucial
 */
var midpoint = totalLength / 2;

/**
 * pastParagraphs - is the text length of the paragraphs we've already moved
 * currentParagraphPos - keeps track of where we are
 * split - we only want to split one paragraph in two
 */
var pastParagraphs = 0            
var currentParagraphPos = 0;
var split = false;

/**
 * iterate over the textLengthArray (i.e. the paragraphs)
 * add them to the left until the text length would of all the paragraphs we've moved
 * into the left would exceed the midpoint. Then split the paragraph the midpoint falls into
 * from there on move paragraphs to the right div.
 */
for (i in textLengthArray) {                
    /**
     * This is the check to insure we aren't past the midpoint
     */
    if (pastParagraphs + textLengthArray[currentParagraphPos] < midpoint) {                    
        /**
         * Move the first paragraph to the left div. 
         * We always move the first because they filter down as we remove them.
         */
        $left.append($('p').eq(0));
        pastParagraphs += textLengthArray[currentParagraphPos];
        currentParagraphPos++;
    }
    else {                    
        /**
         * if we haven't split a paragraph already we should split this first paragraph going right in two.
         */
        if (!split) {
            split = true;

            /**
             * Create two new paragraphs, one for the left, one for the right
             */
            var $goLeft = $(document.createElement("p"));
            var $goRight = $(document.createElement("p"));

            /**
             * The split shouldn't fall in the middle of a word
             * so we run a while loop to find the next available space.
             */
            var splitIndex = midpoint - pastParagraphs;
            var splitPHtml = $('p').eq(0).html();
            while (splitPHtml.charAt(splitIndex) != ' ') {
                splitIndex++;
            }

            /**
             * As we've created two new paragraphs we need to manually remove this one
             */
            $('p').eq(0).remove();

            /**
             * Add the ontent to our new paragraphs and append them to the left and right divs
             */
            $goLeft.html(splitPHtml.substring(0, splitIndex));
            $goRight.html(splitPHtml.substring(splitIndex, splitPHtml.length));
            $left.append($goLeft);
            $right.append($goRight);
        }
        else {                        
            /**
             * Add any further paragraphs to the right div
             */
            $right.append($('p').eq(0));
            currentParagraphPos++;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Finally we want to append our divs to the body.
 */
$('body').append($left);
$('body').append($right);
```